# getting error on try to use wkhtmltopdf.exe and passing 2 params by url

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf

my execute script : `C:\\fortest\\wkhtmltopdf.exe http://localhost:5004/X/Y?a1=1&a2=23 google.pdf`

I getting the error

'a2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

by browser its look like that :
[image]

**I hid some of the data because it could be sensitive**

Comment: Try enclosing url in quotes `C:\\fortest\\wkhtmltopdf.exe "http://localhost:5004/X/Y?a1=1&a2=23" ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose url in quotes:

```
 C:\\fortest\\wkhtmltopdf.exe "http://localhost:5004/X/Y?a1=1&a2=23" ....
```